# wrap a dynamically generated td with anchor tag in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

Please help! I'm fetching RSS feeds from external domain, and I'm generating 's for each item (Title, Date, link) using javascipt, now the 'link' item comes as attribute not link, so how can I make this link as anchor tag or link it with the desired link ?
i.e, how can I wrap this  contents with anchor tag?

Thank you in advance, I appreciate your help.

here it is my script:

```
for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {

        var item = items[i];
        // Get the title from the element.  firstChild is the text node containing
        // the title, and nodeValue returns the value of it.
        var title = item.getElementsByTagName('title')[0].firstChild.nodeValue;
        var pubDate = item.getElementsByTagName('pubDate')[0].firstChild.nodeValue;
       var link =item.getElementsByTagName('link')[0].firstChild.nodeValue;//

        //var link ='<a href="' + item.getElementsByTagName('link')[0].firstChild.nodeValue + '">';//


        var table = document.createElement('table');

        var tr = [];

        var td1 = document.createElement('td');
        var td2 = document.createElement('td');
        var td3 = document.createElement('td');



        var text1 = content.appendChild(document.createTextNode(title));
        var text2 = content.appendChild(document.createTextNode(pubDate));
        var text3 = content.appendChild(document.createTextNode(link));



        for (var i2 = 1; i2 < 4; i2++) {
            tr[i2] = document.createElement('tr');
            for (var j = 1; j < 4; j++) {
                td1.appendChild(text1);
                td2.appendChild(text2);
                td3.appendChild(text3);
                tr[i2].appendChild(td1);
                tr[i2].appendChild(td2);
                tr[i2].appendChild(td3);

            }//End of nested FOR
            table.appendChild(tr[i2]);

        } // end of Parent FOR

        tablearea.appendChild(table);
```

Comment: Could you pl show RSS feed?

Comment: If I've understood your question correctly, you can't, since `a` is not allowed content in `tr`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose there are better ways, such as using `div`s instead of tables, but within the constraints of this question, would it be okay to simply have the same behaviour as an anchor/link? If so, perhaps you can simply add this code to the loop.

Javascript:

```
tr[i2].className="link" //class for some UX hints
tr[i2].onclick=(function(link){
  return function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    location.href=link
  }
})(link)
```

CSS:

```
tr.link {cursor:pointer}
tr.link:hover {background:#FF0}
```

This should allow a user to click anywhere on the row to follow the link

[Example Link](http://jsfiddle.net/mfirdaus/T56bz/)